# stripe.prices.create: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a price on stripe, following this documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create

This is my code:

```
        const stripe_price = await stripe.prices.create({
          product: stripe_product.id,
          unit_amount: parseInt(params.amount),
          currency: 'usd',
          recurring: {
            interval: productDefinition[0].charge_period,
          },
        });
```

My expected output is to get a price object but got "Cannot read property 'create' of undefined".

I can make sure that I imported stripe and stripe version using is 7.15.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Price` resource and APIs shipped at the end of April 2020. This means that you need to be on a recent enough version of stripe-node (or other libraries) to use it. You mentioned that you are on 7.15.0 for stripe-node which shipped in [December 2019](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#7150---2019-12-30) so it's too old to use those new APIs.

to use the `Price` APIs you need to upgrade at least to 8.48.0 as covered in their [changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#8480---2020-04-29).

Comment: Thank you, my bad is that I assumed price API was released with Intent API which was released around version 7.15